# How to write relative url in jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have following url now:

```
http://localhost:8080/testApp/admin/contentModeration
```

by this url I show jsp page.

At this jsp page I want to render image with url:

```
http://localhost:8080/testApp/admin/createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/1
```

testApp is a shifting parameter.

```
<c:url value="admin/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/"></c:url>


<c:url value="/admin/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/"></c:url>
```

doesn't work

How to write `c:url` tag ?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: it means that I as user don't see image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get application name `testApp` with this expression `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` so try maybe something like

```
<c:url value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/1"></c:url>
```

You can also try using relative path. So if your URL looks like

```
http://localhost:8080/testApp/admin/contentModeration
```

but you want to access

```
http://localhost:8080/testApp/admin/createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/1
```

you can use `..` to describe parent context of `contentModeration` which will be `admin` and then add rest of address

```
<c:url value="../createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/1"></c:url>
```